# flask_session session does not preserved in different socketio handlers

Tags: python, flask, websocket, flask-session

I'm trying to understand how sessions work in flask_session extension. I have server-side code:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'top-secret!'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
Session(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, manage_session=False)

@socketio.on('get-session')
def get_session():
    print(session.get('value', 'NO'))

@socketio.on('set-session')
def set_session(data):
    session['value'] = data
    print(session.get('value', 'NO'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

and client:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
with SocketIO('localhost', 5000) as socketio:
    socketio.emit('set-session', '3')
    socketio.emit('get-session')
```

I get following output on server:
3
NO

But i want to get:
3
3

I can't understand why session variable is not preserved. Would appreciate any help.

UPD: execution of the above code results in two different files in \flask_session directory

Comment: the source code is fairly straightforward: https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/blob/master/flask_session/sessions.py#L293 considering you are using filesystem as a session probably want to include more information about your environment and i'd first look to make sure file/directory privileges support this type of use case... obviously this would NOT work in any sort of a distributed system... defaults are: https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/blob/master/flask_session/__init__.py#L71

Comment: Thanks for answering @abigperson! I'm trying to run code on a single windows machine not a distributed system. Execution of the above code results in two different files in \flask_session directory on my disk. I checked source code and notice that open_session function fires twice and in the first time request.cookies.get(app.session_cookie_name) is None, so it generates sid but in the second time request.cookies.get(app.session_cookie_name)  is again None and that's why i can't retrieve my previous session file on disk. Have you any suggestions what can I do next to make it work properly?

Comment: Wish I could offer more assistance. Not entirely familiar with `socketio` or `filesystem` based sessions. The normal Flask session interface passes cookies back and forth to the client (e.g. browser) which is how the information persists between requests. I assume this is what is tripping things up. Maybe this post will help: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-socketio-and-the-user-session

Comment: Yes, I think this is the core issue you are experiencing. When you are calling "get-session" Flask looks for a cookie, which would contain the `sid` but since it is not there it is creating a blank session, hence 2 files. So I think each call to the service must emit the `sid` as well and the client needs to hold onto this value to make this work... good luck!

Comment: Thanks @abigperson! I make it work properly by setting cookie in client-side: `with SocketIO('localhost', 5000, cookies={"session": 'my_session_cookie'}) as socketio:`. I'm trying to make an api based on socketio for an android application. I think that I can generate unique cookie for user and check it in db on server-side but I doubt that this is a proper approach for my problem...